# Session.openActiveSessionFromCache throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I have different Application Id's for my Facebook app, based on which production/test environment the build is targeting.  As a result, I am setting the ApplicationId in code rather than in the manifest.

The first time the app is launched, Session.openActiveSessionFromCache throws a NullPointerException ("Argument 'applicationId' cannot be null").  I catch the error and proceed to create a session using SessionBuilder and user logs in, approves permissions etc.

On all subsequent launches of the application, however, Session.openActiveSessionFromCache continues to throw NullPointerException.  I am expecting it to login the user silently on all subsequent launches.  Why can't I access a cached session when the ApplicationId is set in code rather than metadata?

```
//in MyActivity.onStart()
Session session = null;
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG == true) {
    MY_FACEBOOK_APP_ID = "my debug applicationId";
} else {
    MY_FACEBOOK_APP_ID = "my release applicationId";
}

try {
    session = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(getApplicationContext());
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
if (session == null) {
    session = new Session.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .setApplicationId(MY_FACEBOOK_APP_ID)
        .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I wouldn't use the openActiveSessionFromCache method. Just use the second method and use the Builder to create the session from scratch. It will still use the token cache first, and only prompts the user if they haven't logged in before (or you've cleared the cache by calling closeAndClearTokenInformation).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  What is the purpose of openActiveSessionFromCache then?  Is that designed to recover sessions that have been manually cached (like during orientation change)?

Comment: openActiveSessionFromCache is simply a convenience method that allows you to silently (without user interaction) open a session. It's mainly there to be used if you use the recommended setup (which includes setting the app id in the manifest). If you have a different situation, then you should probably not use it.